# TypeScript, array creation through a loop

Tags: typescript

How to initialize an array through a loop?
The first column is a row, the second number.

[image]

```
  names_month:String[] = ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь",
  "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"];

  statsCreate(data[]:Number)
  {
    return arr =
    [
      [this.names_month[0], data[0]],
      [this.names_month[1], data[1]],
      [this.names_month[2], data[2]],
      [this.names_month[3], data[3]],
      [this.names_month[4], data[4]],
      [this.names_month[5], data[5]],
      [this.names_month[6], data[6]],
      [this.names_month[7], data[7]],
      [this.names_month[8], data[8]],
      [this.names_month[9], data[9]],
      [this.names_month[10], data[10]],
      [this.names_month[11], data[11]]
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Please post *code*, not images of code.

Comment: Array.from({length: n}, (_, i) => i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.map` to create a new array from an original array. `x` is one item of the original array, `xi` is the position of the element in the array.

```js
const namesMonths = [
  'Январь',
  'Февраль',
  'Март',
  'Апрель',
  'Май',
  'Июнь',
  'Июль',
  'Август',
  'Сентябрь',
  'Октябрь',
  'Ноябрь',
  'Декабрь',
];

function statsCreate(data) {
  return data.map((x, xi) => [
    // first element will be one element extracted from the namesMonth array
    namesMonths[xi],
    
    // second element will be one element extracted from the data array
    x,
  ]);
}

console.log(statsCreate(namesMonths));
```